# Is there a built-in function to find the adjoint of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I've been looking for a function that helps me get the adjoint matrix o a given one, I found that you can get the cofactors of a matrix but only by using the "Combinatorica" package, which I couldn't get.

If you know any command or if you know effective ways of creating a function that does this, please help me.

Comment: Can you explain what is the "adjunct"?

Comment: @Szabolcs [Adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) - in Spanish is "Adjunta"

Comment: Take a look at the help for `Minors[]`, under "Applications"

Comment: I've found the translation "adjunt" so I wasn't sure it was the same "adjoint"

Comment: Well, please check the Wikipedia page I linked to be sure

Comment: you're right @belisarius thank you.

Comment: You already gave me the answer @belisarius, should I delete the question?

Comment: @DavidBecharaSenior I don't think so. You could consider writing an answer yourself and accepting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [`Adjugate[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Adjugate.html) is now built-in as of version 13.

For example,

```
m = {{4, 3}, {3, 4}};
Adjugate[m]
   {{4, -3}, {-3, 4}}
```

Check:

```
Simplify[Adjugate[m] == Det[m] Inverse[m]]
   True
```

Answer (score 18):

This is just to get an answer on record so the question can be removed from not-answered list.

The following is taken from an example given in *Application* section of the documentation for [`Minors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minors.html).

> Define the adjoint of a matrix:
>
> ```
> adj[m_] := 
>     Map[Reverse, Minors[Transpose[m], Length[m] - 1], {0, 1}] * 
>       Table[(-1)^(i + j), {i, Length[m]}, {j, Length[m]}]
> ```

Comment: [Well done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106218/152358). But you're wrong: the question gets removed from the unanswered pile only after it has _upvoted_ answers. **Wait**... now you're right :)

Comment: I realize there is a risk involved, but usually there is someone willing to take the bait :)

Comment: We're all for the rep here :)

Comment: @belisarius. Rep? What rep? This is *pro bono* work (CW).

Comment: That was the reason for my smiley!

Comment: This is very slow for a large matrix, any way to boost it a little bit?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse if your matrix has a high probability to have a non 0 determinant, then you can use this in addition to the current answer: `adj2[m_] := Module[{d = Det[m]}, If[d != 0, d Inverse[m], adj[m]]]`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simpler answer:

```
adj[m_] := Inverse[m] Det[m]
```

Comment: Nicely done.$\phantom{}$

Comment: This only works for square matrices.  The [classical adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) (also called the adjugate) can be defined for matrices of any dimension, and the answer above by @m_goldberg is the correct way to do it for non-square matrices.

Comment: And only works if the inverse exists.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Does the accepted answer work for you on non-square matrices? It doesn't for me. I think that's because the {i,length[m]} and {j,length[m]} terms end up making a square table.